# LDO circuit questions

Tags: mosfet, cmos, ldo

I have done a LDO circuit at https://github.com/promach/LDO

I have few questions :

1. Why in the second bode plot (which might be problematic PSRR), gain going up near unity-gain frequency is often a sign of instability ?
2. Why is there some initial noise disturbance around 10us during start-up ?
3. What is the purpose of M2 and M26 ?
4. Could anyone explain the mechanism of transient performance enhancement circuit consisting of M19, M27, M23, M24 and M25 ?
5. Any suggestion on suitable test circuit for load regulation metric check ?

[image: LDO circuit]

[image: transient_simulation]

[image: PSRR_bode_plot]

Comment: Please attach the images your referring to on your question.

Comment: This is a complex design, the left half is clear to me but the right half is not without doing more investigations. I have designed regulators before so LDOs aren't anything new to me. But your questions show that you're new to this. That means you need to work on a simpler design first to learn how to do LDO analysis and design. Normal procedure is that whoever designed this circuit explains to you how it works and why things done in the way that they are.